# How can I get around this "mixed content blocked" error with Blogger?

Tags: javascript, https, hosting

I am trying to add a Javascript picture gallery created with [Wowslider](http://wowslider.com/) to my Blogger blog.

I followed the [instructions on the Wowslider website](http://wowslider.com/rq/how-to-add-jquery-ajax-gallery-to-blogger-1N.html), and I thought I could serve the necessary files, including the images, from my server.

Unfortunately, after I set it all up, it didn't work, and by using Firebug, I discovered that the files on my server won't be shown on the Blogger server because my site uses `http` and Blogger uses `https`. So I was getting an "Blocked loading mixed active content" error.

As far as I can see, there's no way for me to load a directory of Javascript, CSS, HTML, and image files anywhere on the Blogger server.

Converting my website, which is hosted by a service out of my control, to use `https` is not an option.

Is there any way I can host my Wowslider picture gallery in such a way that Blogger will display it?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem is not as bad as I thought.

Blogger only serves pages in `https` mode when you're logged in and editing pages. When a visitor to the site is just viewing the blog, it's in `http` mode.

This means that if you embed a Wowslider into blogger, you won't be able to see it while you're editing it. However, you, and everybody else, will be able to see it after you publish it, log out, and view it as a visitor.

So in the end it works, it's just a little confusing because you won't be able to see the end result until after you publish.